# Rename define function in webpack AMD output

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd

When outputting an AMD module from webpack I need to change the name of the `define` function used in the output bundle.

This is because I am providing a script to a library that namespaces their own `define` function to `Foo.define`.

Given an AMD output webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'MyLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'amd'
  }
};
```

Instead of outputting:

```
define('MyLibrary', [], function() {
    return _entry_return_;
});
```

Webpack would output something like:

```
Foo.define('MyLibrary', [], function() {
    return _entry_return_;
});
```

After 2h of googling I still can't find the correct configuration for webpack or a relevant plugin so I'm asking here.

Appreciate the help!

EDIT:

In the end this is what worked thanks to the answer below:

```
plugins: [].concat(plugins, [
  new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([
    {
      dir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/questions-flow-chart'),
      test: [/bundle\.js$/],
      rules: [
        {
          search: /^define/,
          replace: 'Foo.define'
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [replace-in-file-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file-webpack-plugin)

something like that

```
    plugins: [
        new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([{
            test: [/\.js$/, /\.ts/],
            rules: [{
                search: /define/ig,
                replace: 'foo.define'
            }]
        }])
    ]
```

Comment: This led me to fixing the issue, although initially I had a lot of problems because the above example led to all instances of `undefined` and anything else with the word define in becoming mangled.

Once I altered the regex and narrowed to a single directory I managed to get a working solution - Thanks.

Comment: (Y) glad it helped. share your config. will update the regex here